# Referencing EditText in fragment class of swipe tab caused the Activity to crashed

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext

I am creating a simple student grade calculator with four EditText in a fragment activity of a swipe tab, but referencing the edittext view caused the activity. I have commented the reference code section and the app is no more crashing. below is the class

```
    public static class Course1 extends Fragment implements 

    OnClickListener {

    EditText courseOne, courseTwo, courseThree, courseFour;
    Button compute;
    double sumPoint, proPoint1, proPoint2, cgpa;
    double edit1, edit2, edit3, edit4, sumUnits;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup 
    container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cgpa_one, container, 
    false);
     /**
        courseOne = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        courseTwo = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        courseThree = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText5);
        courseFour = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText6);



        compute.setOnClickListener(this);

        */
        return rootView;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        edit1 = Double.valueOf(courseOne.getText().toString());
        edit2 = Double.valueOf(courseTwo.getText().toString());
        edit3 = Double.valueOf(courseThree.getText().toString());
        edit4 = Double.valueOf(courseFour.getText().toString());


        proPoint1 = edit1 * edit2;
        proPoint2 = edit3 * edit4;

        sumPoint = proPoint1 + proPoint2;
        sumUnits = edit2 + edit4;

        cgpa = (float) sumPoint/sumUnits;

        Intent i = new 
    Intent("com.thenextgeneration.cscumyu.CGPARESULT");
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putDouble("key", cgpa);
        i.putExtras(b);
        startActivity(i);

    }
}
```

I have imported editText in the parent class
Please what way should I follow??

Comment: Please add also logcat, I mean logs of error

Comment: Thanks, I have seen the problem is that I did not reference compute button

Comment: Edit your post and add solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to reference the compute button

by

```
    compute = (Button)rootView.findVieById(R.id.compute);
```

It now work